# WebGPU Smoothen the circumference of circle

Tags: webgpu

I'm new to GPU programming and am learning the basics here.
I've been able to render a circle using tutorials based on https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/webgpu-vertex-buffers.html

The final output though circular does not look smooth due to pixelation.

What more can I do to smoothen the circumference of rendered output?

- I came across functions like smoothstep(), but not sure how to incorporate it in circle drawing.  Totally new concept of Hermite Interpolation for me. Or is it even relevant here!!
- I tried to increase the number of sub-division to 512/1024 but it still feels odd, also not sure it that much division is going to help?

Below is the logic generating circle vertices for drawing circle.
Passing these vertices to shader in single renderPass using draw()

```
createCircleVertices({
    radius = 2,
    numSubdivisions = 1024,
    innerRadius = 0,
    startAngle = 0,
    endAngle = Math.PI * 2,
  } = {}) {

    const numVertices = numSubdivisions * 3 * 2;
    const vertexData = new Float32Array(numSubdivisions * 2 * 3 * 2);

    let offset = 0;
    const addVertex = (x, y) => {
      vertexData[offset++] = x;
      vertexData[offset++] = y;
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < numSubdivisions; ++i) {
      const angle1 = startAngle + (i + 0) * (endAngle - startAngle) / numSubdivisions;
      const angle2 = startAngle + (i + 1) * (endAngle - startAngle) / numSubdivisions;

      const c1 = Math.cos(angle1);
      const s1 = Math.sin(angle1);
      const c2 = Math.cos(angle2);
      const s2 = Math.sin(angle2);

      addVertex(c1 * radius, s1 * radius);
      addVertex(c2 * radius, s2 * radius);
      addVertex(c1 * innerRadius, s1 * innerRadius);

      addVertex(c1 * innerRadius, s1 * innerRadius);
      addVertex(c2 * radius, s2 * radius);
      addVertex(c2 * innerRadius, s2 * innerRadius);
    }
    return vertexData;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called aliasing. There are many techniques for antialiasing. Here's 2 easy ones

1. Render to a higher resolution texture, then scale it down with filtering

   This will have the effect of blending the higher resolution colors when making the lower resolution.

   The disadvantage is it's slower because you're rendering more pixels.

   Here's the circles, on the left they're rendered at 1x resolution. On the right at 4x.

```js
// WebGPU Vertex Buffer vertices - instanced colors
// from https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/webgpu-vertex-buffers-instanced-colors


// A random number between [min and max)
// With 1 argument it will be [0 to min)
// With no arguments it will be [0 to 1)
const rand = (min, max) => {
  if (min === undefined) {
    min = 0;
    max = 1;
  } else if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
};

function createCircleVertices({
  radius = 1,
  numSubdivisions = 24,
  innerRadius = 0,
  startAngle = 0,
  endAngle = Math.PI * 2,
} = {}) {
  // 2 triangles per subdivision, 3 verts per tri, 2 values (xy) each.
  const numVertices = numSubdivisions * 3 * 2;
  const vertexData = new Float32Array(numSubdivisions * 2 * 3 * 2);

  let offset = 0;
  const addVertex = (x, y) => {
    vertexData[offset++] = x;
    vertexData[offset++] = y;
  };

  // 2 vertices per subdivision
  //
  // 0--1 4
  // | / /|
  // |/ / |
  // 2 3--5
  for (let i = 0; i < numSubdivisions; ++i) {
    const angle1 = startAngle + (i + 0) * (endAngle - startAngle) / numSubdivisions;
    const angle2 = startAngle + (i + 1) * (endAngle - startAngle) / numSubdivisions;

    const c1 = Math.cos(angle1);
    const s1 = Math.sin(angle1);
    const c2 = Math.cos(angle2);
    const s2 = Math.sin(angle2);

    // first triangle
    addVertex(c1 * radius, s1 * radius);
    addVertex(c2 * radius, s2 * radius);
    addVertex(c1 * innerRadius, s1 * innerRadius);

    // second triangle
    addVertex(c1 * innerRadius, s1 * innerRadius);
    addVertex(c2 * radius, s2 * radius);
    addVertex(c2 * innerRadius, s2 * innerRadius);
  }

  return {
    vertexData,
    numVertices,
  };
}

async function main() {
  const adapter = await navigator.gpu?.requestAdapter();
  const device = await adapter?.requestDevice();
  if (!device) {
    fail('need a browser that supports WebGPU');
    return;
  }

  // Get a WebGPU context from the canvas and configure it
  const presentationFormat = navigator.gpu.getPreferredCanvasFormat();

  const module = device.createShaderModule({
    code: `
      struct Vertex {
        @location(0) position: vec2f,
        @location(1) color: vec4f,
        @location(2) offset: vec2f,
        @location(3) scale: vec2f,
      };

      struct VSOutput {
        @builtin(position) position: vec4f,
        @location(0) color: vec4f,
      };

      @vertex fn vs(
        vert: Vertex,
      ) -> VSOutput {
        var vsOut: VSOutput;
        vsOut.position = vec4f(
            vert.position * vert.scale + vert.offset, 0.0, 1.0);
        vsOut.color = vert.color;
        return vsOut;
      }

      @fragment fn fs(vsOut: VSOutput) -> @location(0) vec4f {
        return vsOut.color;
      }
    `,
  });

  const pipeline = device.createRenderPipeline({
    label: 'flat colors',
    layout: 'auto',
    vertex: {
      module,
      entryPoint: 'vs',
      buffers: [
        {
          arrayStride: 2 * 4, // 2 floats, 4 bytes each
          attributes: [
            {shaderLocation: 0, offset: 0, format: 'float32x2'},  // position
          ],
        },
        {
          arrayStride: 6 * 4, // 6 floats, 4 bytes each
          stepMode: 'instance',
          attributes: [
            {shaderLocation: 1, offset:  0, format: 'float32x4'},  // color
            {shaderLocation: 2, offset: 16, format: 'float32x2'},  // offset
          ],
        },
        {
          arrayStride: 2 * 4, // 2 floats, 4 bytes each
          stepMode: 'instance',
          attributes: [
            {shaderLocation: 3, offset: 0, format: 'float32x2'},   // scale
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    fragment: {
      module,
      entryPoint: 'fs',
      targets: [{ format: presentationFormat }],
    },
  });

  const kNumObjects = 100;
  const objectInfos = [];

  // create 2 storage buffers
  const staticUnitSize =
    4 * 4 + // color is 4 32bit floats (4bytes each)
    2 * 4;  // offset is 2 32bit floats (4bytes each)
  const changingUnitSize =
    2 * 4;  // scale is 2 32bit floats (4bytes each)
  const staticVertexBufferSize = staticUnitSize * kNumObjects;
  const changingVertexBufferSize = changingUnitSize * kNumObjects;

  const staticVertexBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: 'static vertex for objects',
    size: staticVertexBufferSize,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });

  const changingVertexBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: 'changing vertex for objects',
    size: changingVertexBufferSize,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });

  // offsets to the various uniform values in float32 indices
  const kColorOffset = 0;
  const kOffsetOffset = 4;

  const kScaleOffset = 0;

  {
    const staticVertexValues = new Float32Array(staticVertexBufferSize / 4);
    for (let i = 0; i < kNumObjects; ++i) {
      const staticOffset = i * (staticUnitSize / 4);

      // These are only set once so set them now
      staticVertexValues.set([rand(), rand(), rand(), 1], staticOffset + kColorOffset);        // set the color
      staticVertexValues.set([rand(-0.9, 0.9), rand(-0.9, 0.9)], staticOffset + kOffsetOffset);      // set the offset

      objectInfos.push({
        scale: rand(0.2, 0.5),
      });
    }
    device.queue.writeBuffer(staticVertexBuffer, 0, staticVertexValues);
  }

  // a typed array we can use to update the changingStorageBuffer
  const vertexValues = new Float32Array(changingVertexBufferSize / 4);

  const { vertexData, numVertices } = createCircleVertices({
    radius: 0.5,
    innerRadius: 0.25,
  });
  const vertexBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: 'vertex buffer vertices',
    size: vertexData.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });
  device.queue.writeBuffer(vertexBuffer, 0, vertexData);

  const renderPassDescriptor = {
    label: 'our basic canvas renderPass',
    colorAttachments: [
      {
        // view: <- to be filled out when we render
        clearValue: [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
        loadOp: 'clear',
        storeOp: 'store',
      },
    ],
  };

  function render(canvas, context) {
    // Get the current texture from the canvas context and
    // set it as the texture to render to.
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].view =
        context.getCurrentTexture().createView();

    const encoder = device.createCommandEncoder();
    const pass = encoder.beginRenderPass(renderPassDescriptor);
    pass.setPipeline(pipeline);
    pass.setVertexBuffer(0, vertexBuffer);
    pass.setVertexBuffer(1, staticVertexBuffer);
    pass.setVertexBuffer(2, changingVertexBuffer);

    // Set the uniform values in our JavaScript side Float32Array
    const aspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;

    // set the scales for each object
    objectInfos.forEach(({scale}, ndx) => {
      const offset = ndx * (changingUnitSize / 4);
      vertexValues.set([scale / aspect, scale], offset + kScaleOffset); // set the scale
    });
    // upload all scales at once
    device.queue.writeBuffer(changingVertexBuffer, 0, vertexValues);

    pass.draw(numVertices, kNumObjects);

    pass.end();

    const commandBuffer = encoder.finish();
    device.queue.submit([commandBuffer]);
  }
  
  const canvasToContextMap = new Map();

  const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      const canvas = entry.target;
      const mult = parseInt(canvas.dataset.res);
      const width = entry.contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize * mult;
      const height = entry.contentBoxSize[0].blockSize * mult;
      canvas.width = Math.max(1, Math.min(width, device.limits.maxTextureDimension2D));
      canvas.height = Math.max(1, Math.min(height, device.limits.maxTextureDimension2D));
      // re-render
      render(canvas, canvasToContextMap.get(canvas));
    }
  });

  document.querySelectorAll('canvas').forEach(canvas => {
    const context = canvas.getContext('webgpu');
    context.configure({
      device,
      format: presentationFormat,
    });
    canvasToContextMap.set(canvas, context);
    observer.observe(canvas);
  });
}

function fail(msg) {
  alert(msg);
}

main();
```

```css
@import url(https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/resources/webgpu-lesson.css);
html, body {
  margin: 0;       /* remove the default margin          */
  height: 100%;    /* make the html,body fill the page   */
}

.split {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.split>* {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas {
  display: block;  /* make the canvas act like a block   */
}
```

```html
<div class="split">
  <canvas data-res="1"></canvas>
  <canvas data-res="4"></canvas>
</div>
```

Note: the browser generally uses linear filtering to draw the canvas's texture into the page so we didn't have do anything special. All we had to do is make the resolution of the canvas higher than its CSS display size.  To do that I added [a `dataset` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). In the `ResizeObserver` callback I multiply the width and height from the observer by the value of that attribute.

2. Render to a multisampled texture then "resolve" it

   A multisampled texture is a special kind of texture that's generally some integer multiple of higher resolution than you're final result. When you draw a triangle, the edges are drawn in a special way to using that higher resolution. You then "resolve" the texture (which is a fancy way of saying you copy it to a lower resolution texture) which in the process, ends up blending the colors in the edges.

   This is similar to the previous solution. It's advantage over the previous solution is that you're only rendering more pixels at the edges of triangle, not in the middle so it's faster. The disadvantage is you only get certain resolution choices in multiples.

The sample above is too big to repeat so here's a just a triangle rendered with multisampling

```js
// WebGPU Simple Triangle
// from https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/webgpu-simple-triangle.html


async function main() {
  const adapter = await navigator.gpu?.requestAdapter();
  const device = await adapter?.requestDevice();
  if (!device) {
    fail('need a browser that supports WebGPU');
    return;
  }

  const presentationFormat = navigator.gpu.getPreferredCanvasFormat();
  const module = device.createShaderModule({
    label: 'our hardcoded red triangle shaders',
    code: `
      @vertex fn vs(
        @builtin(vertex_index) vertexIndex : u32
      ) -> @builtin(position) vec4f {
        let pos = array(
          vec2f( 0.0,  0.5),  // top center
          vec2f(-0.5, -0.5),  // bottom left
          vec2f( 0.5, -0.5)   // bottom right
        );

        return vec4f(pos[vertexIndex], 0.0, 1.0);
      }

      @fragment fn fs() -> @location(0) vec4f {
        return vec4f(1, 1, 0, 1);
      }
    `,
  });

  const pipeline = device.createRenderPipeline({
    label: 'our hardcoded red triangle pipeline',
    layout: 'auto',
    vertex: {
      module,
      entryPoint: 'vs',
    },
    fragment: {
      module,
      entryPoint: 'fs',
      targets: [{ format: presentationFormat }],
    },
    // setup this pipeline so we can draw to a multisampled texture
    multisample: {
      count: 4,
    },
  });

  const renderPassDescriptor = {
    label: 'our basic canvas renderPass',
    colorAttachments: [
      {
        // view: <- to be filled out when we render
        clearValue: [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
        loadOp: 'clear',
        storeOp: 'store',
      },
    ],
  };


  // Get a WebGPU context from the canvas and configure it
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('webgpu');
  context.configure({
    device,
    format: presentationFormat,
  });

  const canvasTexture = context.getCurrentTexture();

  // Create a multisampled texture
  const multisampledTexture = device.createTexture({
    size: [canvasTexture.width, canvasTexture.height],
    format: presentationFormat,
    sampleCount: 4,
    usage: GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
  });


  // Set the color attachment to the multisampled texture
  // and set the "resolveTarget" to the texture we want the
  // multisampled texture resolved to
  renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].view = multisampledTexture.createView();
  renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].resolveTarget =
      canvasTexture.createView();

  // make a command encoder to start encoding commands
  const encoder = device.createCommandEncoder({ label: 'our encoder' });

  // make a render pass encoder to encode render specific commands
  const pass = encoder.beginRenderPass(renderPassDescriptor);
  pass.setPipeline(pipeline);
  pass.draw(3);  // call our vertex shader 3 times.
  pass.end();

  const commandBuffer = encoder.finish();
  device.queue.submit([commandBuffer]);

}

function fail(msg) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
  alert(msg);
}

main();
```

```css
@import url(https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/resources/webgpu-lesson.css);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Note: You can combine both techniques 1 and 2